# I want to get a day of week then pass into stored procedure in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT DATENAME(dw,'" +txtdate.Text+ "') as theDayName;
string result = ((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dayname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = result;
```

Here got an error at result which is not stored day of week.

Comment: Pass txtdate.text value in procedure and use date name function in store procedure, any specific reason to pass from here ?

Comment: why are you not sending txtdate.Text  as a parameter in the procedure and  you can run the select command in procedure and get the dayname . It will save one call of db atleast.

Comment: I think  you should use `sqlcmd` like `string result = ((string)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar());` ;).

Comment: Provide the format of date entered in txtDate. Also paste the exact error.

Comment: Thanq for ur valuable replies... i got answer